# “Unable to Load” message in Today's Widget in iOS 11

Tags: ios, objective-c, widget

On all my test devices and simulators running iOS 11 my widgets failing to load. Just a message in the center "Unable to load". Not visible "Show more"/"Show less" also. Cannot open the app when tap on the widget.

On all iOS 10.x.x devices/simulators everything is fine.

Tried restart devices, delete app and install again from the App Store. Tried remove widget and add again. Tried with new build of the app using last Xcode (9.0), without success.

Any assumptions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the reason..

Here [Apple Developer Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Today.html) I found this for the widget's plist.file:

"If you don’t want to use the storyboard file provided by the template, remove the NSExtensionMainStoryboard key and add the NSExtensionPrincipalClass key, using the name of your view controller for the value."

So, when I remove NSExtensionMainStoryboard key, works in iOS 11, no "Unable to load" message, the widget looks good, when tap on the widget, my app starts.